# How to use Handler / runnable?

Tags: android, handler, runnable

I would like my code runs all the one minut..
Can anyone explain me how to do it?

```
private Handler myHandler;
    private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //DO WORK
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      myHandler.postDelayed(this,60000);
        }
    };      
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
 super.onCreate();      
             //call function
             myHandler = new Handler();
            //
        myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable,60000);

 Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "onCreate");
}
```

Comment: If you want to run it every minute you should use a timer: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Is it inside a service?

Comment: The code you pasted should work as long as the enclosing Service exists. What is your problem exactly? DO you get any exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 0):

A Timer is a valid solution but it will not execute on the UI thread. And your code tells me this is what you want.

The simplest way to do that would be via a handler and a repeating task:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); // ui thread handler
handler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(handler), INETRVAL);
```

Where:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       // do periodical action here

       // and.. repeat your task <------------
       handler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(handler), INETRVAL);
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.                                            Now if I whant my code runs for a minute all the 5 hours?

Answer (score 0):

watch this http://goo.gl/DRdaUi

BTW 60 second is a very long time for thread to run! If you have something that runs this long consider using android service instead of thread.

Also do you need to use handler? think again, most of the time there is no need for that. AsyncTask is android first option for multithreading and its a lot simpler. unless AsyncTask can not handle what you have in your mind don't use any other method.